# Read json values using sed or awk. I am not allowed to use jq

Tags: json, awk, sed

For the following json data, I need to retrieve the value of the status. I tried to look for examples online and adopt the same, but couldn't do it successfully as this json has arrays. Can you please help me retrieving the "status" in the following json?

This is how the jq version looks `echo $JSON | jq -r .data.affected_items[].status` I need the same using

```
{
  "data": {
    "affected_items": [
      {
        "os": {
          "arch": "x86_64",
          "major": "2",
          "name": "Amazon Linux",
          "platform": "amzn",
          "uname": "Linux |ip-10-179-120-6.vpc.internal |4.14.256-197.484.amzn2.x86_64 |#1 SMP Tue Nov 30 00:17:50 UTC 2021 |x86_64",
          "version": "2"
        },
        "manager": "wazuh-manager-worker-0",
        "dateAdd": "2022-02-24T08:42:52Z",
        "lastKeepAlive": "2022-03-08T04:33:44Z",
        "group": [
          "default"
        ],
        "name": "ec2_us-west-2_279976188247_i-030ccd7d70b84f0ee",
        "ip": "10.179.120.6",
        "configSum": "ab73af41699f13fdd81903b5f23d8d00",
        "node_name": "wazuh-manager-worker-0",
        "status": "active",
        "version": "Wazuh v4.1.5",
        "mergedSum": "56dfa0edef630b932284df2f81bf4a1c",
        "id": "006",
        "registerIP": "any"
      }
    ],
    "total_affected_items": 1,
    "total_failed_items": 0,
    "failed_items": []
  },
  "message": "All selected agents information was returned",
  "error": 0
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use python? If not, _why_? Using `sed` or `awk` for parsing json is more compilcated and error prone than using a proper json parser.

Comment: I assume you're asking for help parsing the input to jq, not the output from it, but you haven't shown us that input so we can t help you parse it with any other tool. Make sure to add the expected final output too.

Comment: Yeah I am actually working on a python script in which I need to address reading the json value. @TedLyngmo

Comment: OutPut I needed is the value of "status" i.e, "active"

Comment: What if there are more than one affected item?

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*"status": \("[^"]*"\).*/\1/p' file
"active"
```

then edit your question to contain a better explanation of your requirements and more truly representative sample input/output that the above doesn't work for.